# How can I pass object id in mock_data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using NodeJS in my e-commerce app, I passed categories and items MOCK_DATA, but as items have `items_categories` field which should be related to the category model ,I want to do it in my data too.

for example here is my Product Model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    items_name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please provide items_name"],
      maxlength: 100,
    },
    items_name_ar: {
      type: String,
    },
    items_desc: {
      type: String,
      //   default: "",
    },
    items_desc_ar: {
      type: String,
    },
    items_image: {
      type: String,
    },
    items_count: {
      type: Number,
    },
    items_active: {
      type: Number,
    },
    items_price: {
      type: Number,
    },
    items_discount: {
      type: Number,
    }, 
    items_categories: { //catagory should be linked with reference to category model provided below
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

and here is my category.js model:

```
const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    categories_name: {
      type: String,
    },
    categories_name: {
      type: String,
    },
    categories_name_ar: {
      type: String,
    },
    categories_image: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema);
```

assuming that this is my mock_data.json file:

```
[
  {
    "items_name": "laptop 2",
    "items_name_ar": "sesese",
    "items_desc": "laptop 2 ",
    "items_desc_ar": "seeee12",
    "items_image": "https://res.crereereg",
    "items_count": 5,
    "items_active": 1,
    "items_price": 200,
    "items_discount": 10,
    "item_categories": "6450d0e5f2e4596478b01ec4"//how can I pass the categories ObjectId?
  },etc
]
```

here is my **populate** method if needed:

```
import { readFile } from "fs/promises";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

import connectDB from "./db/connect.js";
import Product from "./models/Product.js";

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL);
    await Product.deleteMany();
    const jsonProducts = JSON.parse(
      await readFile(new URL("./MOCKDATA.json", import.meta.url))
    );
    await Product.create(jsonProducts);
    console.log("success");
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

start();
```